# Why in an object is the property with its values as an array being sent to the server in a string format

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, server, body-parser

I am having the client push this object to the a server.

```
 var person = {
                name: $("#name").val().trim(),
                photourl: $("#image").val().trim(),
                questions: $('select.form-control')
                            .map(function () {
                               return this.value;
                              }).get();
                            };                      
 console.log(person.questions);

 // Send the information to the server from the clientside
 $.post("/survey", person)
   .done(function (data) {
     console.log(data);
     alert("Adding character...");
   });
```

I am retrieving this data on the server using this code:

```
app.post("/survey", function(req, res){
        var incomingPerson = req.body;
        console.log(incomingPerson);
});
```

When I log the incomingPerson, this is the result:

```
{   name: 'veena',
    photourl: 'abc',
    'questions[]': [ '4', '2', '3', '1', '2', '2', '4', '5', '1', '3' ] 
}
```

I am able to access all other properties as I would access an object property

i.e `console.log(incomingPerson.name)//veena` or `console.log(incomingPerson.photUrl) //abc`

However, when I try to access the property with the array, I get undefined:

```
console.log(incomingPerson.questions) //undefined
```

QUESTION:
**Why is the property with its values as an array being sent to the server that way ...in a string format ?**
I am able to access it using `incomingPerson['questions[]']` but not `incomingPerson.questions`

Comment: What is this `.get()` that you call after `.map(...)`? It's not a method of Array...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get

Comment: it's the one thats getting the value associated with the class in my example

Comment: Try to serialize your object `person` before sending it to the server with `$.post("/survey", JSON.stringify(person)` and see what happens. Unless your class implements a custom `map()` method that returns a `Map` instead of an `Array`, or you have modified some object prototypes, I cannot understand how your code does not throw when evaluating `questions`.

Comment: yeah the stringify works. its returning an an object so I had to turn it to a string.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{   name: 'veena',
photourl: 'abc',
'questions['foo', 'bar']': [ '4', '2', '3', '1', '2', '2', '4', '5', '1', '3' ]
```

}

If that is what you want to accomplish, the simple answer is that you cannot use an array as the key to another element.

Hope these helps.. ;)

Comment: {   name: 'veena',
photourl: 'abc',
questions: [ '4', '2', '3', '1', '2', '2', '4', '5', '1', '3' ] 
 This is what I want the client to sent to the server

Comment: but for some reason its sending it 'questions[]': [ '4', '2', '3', '1', '2', '2', '4', '5', '1', '3' ]

Comment: @VeenaUppalapati log the person object before then check if it identical to what you have on the server. Some time it maybe cause by typographical error.

Comment: its showing correctly in the client side.  its only changing its format when retrieved by the server.  So I don't think it's typographical error